# How to count leaf node from graph database Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, nodes

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/graphpw.png/

I would like to know how I can get the number of leaf node from certain node using method or something in neo4j ?

Example.

At Node A --> contains 12 leaf nodes
At Node B --> contains 6 leaf nodes

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would model the intermediate relationships as `contains` and the leaf relationships as `leaf`, see http://console.neo4j.org/r/ulo3yc

Then, you can do

With a setup of

```
create (f1{name:'folder1'}), ({name:'root'})-[:contains]->(f1)-[:leaf]->   (f2{name:'folder2'}), f1-[:leaf]->({name:'folder3'})
```

you can do something like

```
start root=node(1) 
match root-[:contains*0..]->()-[:leaf]->leaf 
return leaf
```

returning

```
+-------------------------+
| leaf                    |
+-------------------------+
| Node[2]{name:"folder2"} |
| Node[3]{name:"folder3"} |
+-------------------------+
```